# About Java Assignment Operator

Tags: java, class, inheritance

If i define

```
class A {

public int a;
public float b;
public A() { 
a = 10;
}
}

class B extends A {

public B() {
a = 2;
}
}

class C extends A {

public C() {
b = 2.0f;
}
}
```

And in main

```
public static void main(//...) {

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();

a = b; //error?
b = c; //this one too?
```

}

Comment: Do you get an error or do you want to know if it generates an error?

Comment: Wanna What will exactly happen... Value get assign? or it just ignore the assignment and continue the program to the end? or it is abruptly stop? and if i wrote b = a, what will happen to b? it'll become class A or just the value in b's that inherit from A changes...

Comment: If that's the whole concern, why don't you just compile and run it **yourself** and determine the errors and/or learn from the errors?

Comment: oops i accidentally pressed delete T T and delete one of the answer unfortunately... I am sorry, didn't mean it..

Comment: Well, I want to know what's behind, not just the result

Comment: @biloon: no the author has deleted the answer himself since he realized that it was wrong :) And as to the final concern, you should have asked that explicitly in your question. "Why does it give a compilation error with *Type Mismatch* "? Right now you're overcoming like a lazy who don't want to make his homework ;)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about the first error, it looks fine. You should in future post the **exact** error message along it. You should never ignore error messages since they tell something about the cause of the problem. The second error is obvious, it's a *type mismatch*: `C` does not `extends B`, so you cannot assign an instance of `C` to a reference which is declared as `B`. To fix it, you should declare it as `C`, `A` or `Object` (since it is the *implicit* superclass of all classes).

Further, your `class C` doesn't compile since the constructor is named `A()` instead of `C()`, but that'll probably be a copypaste error ;)

#### See also:

- [Inheritance tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)